# How can I provide my react-native app with google sign in?

Tags: reactjs, google-api, react-native, google-signin

I`ve tried to register my app as Web application, generate the user id and implement it in my code but get an error when I press my button for log in with google:
 [Unhandled promise rejection: Error: Please provide the appropriate client ID.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AZRzC.png)

Comment: You need to create a project in google firebase or cloud console and do some settings. You can use https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-google-signin and see installation docs.

Comment: are you using Expo? read the documentation here, https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/google/

Comment: @slashsharp , yes, I use expo, but it does not work for me, I did all steps by instructions. Do I need to register my app as web or android?

Comment: @AlinaFrolova Hello! If you have solved this problem, can you please leave feedback as you did? I’ve been struggling with this problem for several days.

Comment: Anyone any update on this? Got an identical problem: it works in Expo, it doesnt when I build the apk

Answer (score 0):

If you're using expo, you have to configure the `google` sign-in like this. This is my configuration. You have to create `androidClientId` and `iosClientId` from your account and use it here.

*Disclaimer:* This is a standalone function only for *signingin/signingup* a `Google` user and fetching details. To configure it with firebase you have to add other functions too.

Also, make sure that you're importing this package. I faced a similar problem when I used another package.

`import * as Google from 'expo-google-app-auth'`

Additionally, are you using the latest version of  `expo` SDK?

```
 async signInWithGoogleAsync() {
        try {
            const result = await Google.logInAsync({
                androidClientId:
                    'your-id',
                iosClientId:
                    'your-id',
                scopes: ['profile', 'email'],
                permissions: ['public_profile', 'email', 'gender', 'location']
            })
            if (result.type === 'success') {
          /*put your logic here, I set some states and navigate to home screen 
             after successful signin.*/
                const googleUser = result.user
                this.setState({
                    email: googleUser.email,
                    name: googleUser.name,
                })
                this.navigateToLoadingScreen() 
                return result.accessToken
            } else {
                return { cancelled: true }
            }
        } catch (e) {
            return { error: true }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Hello dude! Can you help here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62860618/why-googlesignin-works-on-local-server-but-doesnt-works-on-my-android
Bless you!